# Any language binding for MFC?

Tags: user-interface, mfc, winapi

THere are a lot of wrappers for toolkits like Qt, Cocoa or WxWidgets for D, Python, Ruby and other languages.

I wonder if anyone has ever written a binding for MFC ?

Comment: While this is possible, I'm wondering why MFC would be your choice for integrating with a more modern dynamic language when the .NET framework supports languages like IronRuby and IronPython.

Do you need to use MFC vs. WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Well i used the languages as an example because nobody else then me is using Eiffel for a GUI Application :-)

And Eiffel compiles native and this is the only reason. If the unique selling point of your product is speed you can't go .NET
QT might be the alternative but not  WPF or WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i did it.

Some of the intrinsics of MFC are so dominant that i had to change to API's of my wrapper. For example you have to reverse the control flow to get the dialog resource template processing done.

But it works. And it works fine now.

I'm now happy to be able to program and use third party MFC components in Eiffel without message maps and other old weird stuff.

This is now much better then QT.

Answer (score 1):

MFC is not a language so I can't see how (or why) there should be such wrapper.

Comment: MFC is totally bound to C++, so this question makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This has been done for python:

[Python Programming on Win32 using PythonWin](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/python/excerpts/chpt20/pythonwin.html)

Comment: They are using Win32 which is miles away (exact 5 million bytes) from MFC